# How does task cancellation work in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

When running delete-by-query on elasticsearch, some tasks take a very long time and I am manually monitoring their status and trying to canceling those tasks running over 10 minutes. After cancellation, the status of a task becomes like `{completed: true, total: 1000, deleted: 400}`. What does this really mean?

Is the task partially completed? Now if I send the same delete-by-query request, it would give me `total == 600`.

Or the task is completely discarded. Running the same request would still have `total == 1000`

What's the mechanism/behavior of task cancellation in elasticsearch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experiment with ES 6.2, when a deletion task gets canceled, it's irreversible. Meaning if 400 out of 1000 documents get deleted before the task is canceled, that task is marked as completed with 400 documents completely gone. The total number of docs become 600.